# Unable to install Firebase in ionic 4 on OS X

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, npm

Followed instructions in Firebase documentation and executed:

```
sudo npm install firebase --save
```

I am getting the following errors. Any help would be appreciated. Previously I have successfully installed firebase on ionic 3. However, this may have nothing to do with ionic.

```
1564 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
1565 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/syedtariq/.npm-global/bin/npm" "install"
1566 verbose node v11.0.0
1567 verbose npm  v6.4.1
1568 error code ELIFECYCLE
1569 error errno 1
1570 error grpc@1.16.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
1570 error Exit status 1
1571 error Failed at the grpc@1.16.0 install script.
1571 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
1572 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because it cannot install the native C++ `gRCP` add-on. Try to use the [grcp-node](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node) module instead which does not require native C++ addon.

**edit**: grpc has some issues with node@11 see: [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1363) You need to downgrade to node@10

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am not sure how to fix this issue. It works fine when I build an ionic 3 app. On the ionc 3 app, the file package.json has no reference to grpc. The package-lock.json has a reference to grpc version 1.13.1.

Comment: Some of your primary dependency requires it. Do you say, that you can build your app on different platform, but when you try to build on your laptop  it fails?

Comment: I am only building on a macbook pro with macOD Mojave Vesion 10.14.2 Beta. As I indicated, the installation works fine if I use ionic 3.

Comment: Correction: I am having the problem BOTH on ionic 3 and 4. This suggests that something changed in my environment. It may have been triggered by an OS update. I will try reverting to a previous OS version and see it it helps.

Comment: what node version do you use? Ah I see, it is node@11 I edited my answer, you need to downgrade to node@10

Answer (score 0):

[another solution](https://www.fahidjavid.com/fix-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir/)This is an issue that is very widely issued on the github site by numerous persons. The solution recommended by lependu (falling back to an LTS version of node) worked in one project. In another project a similar error started when I did a 'sudo npm install'. Very frustrating. I finally found an additional solution which worked: [enter link description here](https://www.fahidjavid.com/fix-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir/). It required me to add to the npm install command as follows:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

After two days, i came to:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm update
```

and done.